# Moving files from Azure Blob Storage to Salesforce

Tags: azure, salesforce, azure-blob-storage

How can I move files from Azure Blob Storage to Salesforce?

Comment: You can use Copy Activity in Azure Data Factory to copy data from and to Salesforce. please check this https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/connector-salesforce?tabs=data-factory

Answer (score 1):

You can use Azure Data Factory to copy the files from Azure Blob Storage to Salesforce.

Please follow the below steps to copy the files from Azure Blob Storage to Salesforce

1. Open Azure Data Factory Studio.
2. Click on Manage. In the Linked Services, click on New, search for    Salesforce and add your Salesforce Account.

[image]

3. In the similar way, add a new Linked Service for Azure Blob Storage and add your Blob Storage.
4. Now Click on Author. Click on +, select Copy Data tool.

[image]

5. Add source as Azure Blob Storage  and destination as Salesforce and fill the details.

In this way, you can copy files from Azure Blob Storage to Salesforce.

**Reference** :
https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/connecting-salesforce-azure-blob-storage-mukul-mahawariya/?published=t